# Sending Network Request as soon as device is unlocked

Tags: ios, background-fetch

Apologies if this question has already been asked but during my search of stackoverflow i could not find an exact answer to this question.

Is there any allowed way that my app can make a network request as soon as the iOS device is unlocked ?

All of the methods describe to listen to unlock notification involve `com.apple.springboard.lockcomplete` which is not really allowed by apple. Is there any other possible way ?

Comment: no, apple has its own process for handling background tasks. You should read up on all the available background modes, background-fetch etc. Non of these support that

Comment: I know that is the problem. Background-fetch etc will not tell me when the device is unlocked and i only want to send the request as soon as the device is unlocked.

Comment: I understand, thats why I said in my comment that its not possible and these modes don't support that. Tracking when a user unlocks there phone outside your app also sounds like something you shouldn't be doing and I wouldn't install an app that did such a thing. Its invasive to track things outside the app, and apple make this impossible or extremely difficult by sandboxing all apps

Comment: There should have been a close vote option for questions try to exploit security vulnerabilities.

Comment: Well the app doesn't have any malicious intention but you are right it could be thought of as such.

Answer (score 0):

If you initialize your Network Manager class (like Alamofire.Manager) In applicationWillEnterForeground of AppDelegate it should work fine.

Comment: Yeah but i don't want to send the request in `applicationWillEnterForeground`. That will only work when the user will tap on my app. What i want is that whenever the user unlocks the device regardless of whether he opens my app or not. My app should be able to send a network request.